# In which table are subscription tags saved?

Tags: postgresql, backend, odoo

I'm currently working with the database of Odoo to bulk import and export data. For that I also use tags. For example I need to bulk tag 500 subscriptions. Does anyone know in which tables the relations between model and tag are saved in?

I already found those:

- **res_partner_res_partner_category_rel**
- **sale_subscription_template_tag_rel**

What I'm looking for are the tags on subscription level. Through the URL I can see, that the model I'm looking at is "sale.subscription". Therefore I started looking for a table named "sale_subscription_tag_relation" but there is nothing. sale_subscription_template_tag_rel is empty while there are already subscriptions tagged. So it can't be that.

The information shown on the UI needs to be stored somewhere, but I just can't find out where. The URL im looking at:

https://localhost/web#id=CUSTOMER_ID&action=454&active_id=1779&model=sale.subscription&view_type=form&cids=1&menu_id=329

Tables for the subscription model:

```
sale_subscription
sale_subscription_alert
sale_subscription_alert_sale_subscription_template_rel
sale_subscription_close_reason
sale_subscription_close_reason_wizard
sale_subscription_line
sale_subscription_price_wizard
sale_subscription_snapshot
sale_subscription_stage
sale_subscription_template
sale_subscription_template_tag_rel
sale_subscription_wizard
sale_subscription_wizard_option
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [relation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2many) name is not specified, Odoo will compute it based on the alphabetical order of the [tables names](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/fields.py#L3676-L3684) (model, comodel).

```
tables = sorted([model._table, comodel._table])
self.relation = '%s_%s_rel' % tuple(tables)
```

Check in `sale.subscription` model if the relation parameter is set on the tags field and if not, use the above code to compute it ( The comodel name is usually the first parameter of the Many2many field).

**Edit:**

For example, the [tag_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/event/models/event_event.py#L55) field defined in the event module does not specify the relation.

The comodel name is `event.tag` and the field is defined in `event.type` model, to get the table names, we need to replace `.` with `_` to get the table names.

In the following code, we will [sort](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics) the model and comodel table names in ascending order and use the result to construct the relation name using [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)  (It will replace the `%s` with a table name in the provided order)

```
>>> tables = sorted(['event_type', 'event_tag'])
>>> tables
['event_tag', 'event_type']
>>> relation = '%s_%s_rel' % tuple(tables)
>>> relation
'event_tag_event_type_rel'
```

There should be a table named `event_tag_event_type_rel` in the database after installing the module.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find any column named "tag" in sale_subscription. The code looks like it is Python which I'm pretty unfamiliar with. Could you please provide additional explanation?

Comment: Of course, check my edit.

Comment: Thanks again. I actually looked into every table containing "rel" in the name, but I just can't find out where the tags are saved. The tags on the customer level are saved in res_partner_res_partner_category_rel and the usable tags in res_partner_category. Something similar has to exist for the sale subscription model, but I just cant find it. Tables with sale_subscription in the name edited into question

Comment: You just need to know the model and comodel names, please provide the field definition.

Comment: I don't know the comodel name. I just know that it allows users to add a tag to the model. I neither know where those tags are saved nor what Odoo calls them. I didn't setup the system, so unfortunately I also can't tell what models are installed by default and what is added by an editor. Do you have an idea how I can find out, which comodel is used when adding a tag to the subscription?

Comment: Go to `Settings/Technical/Database Structure/Models`, find the `sale.subscription` model then click on the tags field inside the `Fields` tab to open the form view. The value of the comodel name is the value of the `Related Model` field.

Comment: The model sale.subscription was the comodel to account.analytic.tag. So the name of the table was account_analytic_tag_sale_subscription_rel. Thanks for helping!